# Support for building Java/maven projects?

Tags: java, linux, maven, visual-studio-code

Folks,

as the subject says: Can anyone provide a quick outline how to use Visual Studio Code for building Java projects using Apache Maven? Is this supported / possible?

Thanks in advance,
Kristian

Comment: Maybe, you can use Tasks, docs on https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks, an example http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2015/10/28/visual-studio-code-tasks

Comment: Thanks - it takes a bit more effort to get it done than in some of the heavier Java IDEs but generally works.

Answer (score 0):

Simple tasks.json for Apache Maven, assuming it's in $PATH and the project uses a default maven lifecycle.

```
{
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "command": "mvn",
 "isShellCommand": true,
 "args": ["-X", "clean","install"],
 "showOutput": "always"
}
```

Thanks for pointing me to the right place.